# Remove Popcorn Ceiling without Asbestos, what kind of specialist should I hire?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, paint, popcorn

I want to remove Popcorn ceiling from 300 sq foot living room. The Ceiling does Not have asbestos, (I confirmed), and was built 1985. It will also be repainted with basic White Paint.

Who should I hire to conduct this?

a) Drywall Person

b) or General Painter?

Both Industries personnel when calling claim they can remove it. So wondering who would be ideal person, or does it matter?

Comment: This is a DIY  site.  **You can do it**. If it has not been painted it is very easily scraped off. https://www.amazon.com/Homax-6100-Ceiling-Texture-Scraper/dp/B0002YSQSW/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=popcorn+ceiling+removal+tool&qid=1608431358&sr=8-3  A specialist is not required.

Comment: Hire a *plasterer* (maybe same as what you call "drywall person" but not the same thing in my locale). The plsterer will definitely be able to deal with any wall-surface issues related to the work. He/she may or may not be also willing to paint afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removal is the easy part for popcorn texture.

Fixing nail or screw divots and making sure tape joints are smooth will be more work than the removal.

I would suggest a licensed handyman as they are cheaper than contractors and this is very simple work and easily done by a home owner.

I mention the tape and divot repair because when we shot popcorn we really did not do a good job at all with finishing the tape and nail holes, after the basic clean up and hole filling joint sanding you will want some texture even if a very light orange peal from a spray can.

If you don’t want to do this a handyman would be cheaper and he may even have a texture gun to spray the ceiling.

No texture and the slightest divots and tape lines are visible.

Answer (score 1):

Painters are probably better at covering and protecting your furniture etc., they do that every time they work. Drywall people generally work when there is NO furniture etc. in the room yet.